Is it safe to disable PayPal_Braintree module?
PayPal_Braintree is dumping this in the logs. Is it safe to delete PayPal_Braintree/PayPal_BraintreeGraphQL module
Braintree\Configuration::merchantId needs to be set (or accessToken needs to be passed to Braintree\Gateway).
